# Вопрос про SortedSet и Comparer

Tags: c#

Есть `SortedSet`. Для сравнения использую стандартный метод `CompareTo()`.

```
SortedSet<int> set = new SortedSet<int>(Comparer<int>.Create((a, b) => a.CompareTo(b)));  

set.Add(2);
set.Add(6);
set.Add(6);
set.Add(7);
set.Add(4);
set.Add(11);
```

Здесь в `set` находится 5 значений: `2, 4, 6, 7, 11`. Что мне нужно сделать, чтобы в `set` попадали не только уникальные значения (в моем случае в `set` должны содержаться `2, 4, 6, 6, 7, 11`)?

Comment: SortedSet не допускает повторяющихся значений см. [документацию](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/dd412070(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_7). В общем то выход тут только один, реализовать свою коллекцию. Можно подсмотреть как реализован SortedSet, код доступен в [исходниках](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/dd412070(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_7) либо использовать List и сортировать после каждой вставки элемента, как в ответах ниже

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Никак, коллекции реализующие интерфейс [`ISet<T>`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.iset-1?view=netframework-4.7) *по определению* не могут содержать дублированных элементов. Используйте обычный [`List<T>`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1?view=netframework-4.7).

Элегантный способ с LINQ:

```
List<int> lst = new List<int>(){ 4, 2, 7, 6, 11, 6 };
var sorted = lst.OrderBy(t => t).ToList(); // 2, 4, 6, 6, 7, 11
```

*учтите, что это создает новый список в памяти, что может негативно сказаться на производительности для больших списков.

Answer (score 0):

Используйте другой контейнер, например `List<int>`, после добавления элементов вызовите метод `Sort`.

Answer (score 0):

Не знаю, стоит так делать или нет, но в `SortedSet<int>` можно добавить одинаковые элементы. Метод `CompareTo()` эквивалентен записи: `a > b ? 1 : a < b ? -1 : 0`. То есть, если элемент уже содержится в `set`, то этот элемент не добавляется. Но, если заменить в условии `0` на `-1`, то компаратор просто поставит  одинаковые элементы друг перед другом:

```
SortedSet<int> set = new SortedSet<int>(Comparer<int>.
   Create((a, b) => a > b ? 1 : a < b ? -1 : -1));         
set.Add(2);
set.Add(6);
set.Add(6);
set.Add(7);
set.Add(4);
set.Add(11);
```

Здесь `set` содержит `2, 4, 6, 6, 7, 11`.

Comment: Добавление и итерация по множеству, как видно, продолжают работать. А проверка на наличие элемента? Не знаю, как в шарпе называется. `Contains`?

Comment: Да, `Contains`. Он не работает. Я так понимаю, как раз из-за `-1` условия и наличия повторяющихся элементов?

Comment: @Sv__t: Такой компаратор запрещён документацией. С ним может происходить всё, что угодно, никаких гарантий правильного поведения.

Comment: @Sv__t из-за того, что он теперь никогда не возвращает 0, что указывает на совпадение с искомым элементом.